# horizontal lines in renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lines

I am here to ask for help for a problem that I often (not always!) encounter, especially when I deal with sea and water.
I am attaching a render and a close-up, both photoshopped to increase the contrast and the visibility of the flaw: horizontal lines. You can see them clearly across the letters, and less clearly across the water.
Like I said, I have experienced this problem in more than one project. What could be the cause?

[image: scene and close-up]

Comment: Aren't these reflections? If there is no object casting this reflection, it could be a light source or an environment HDRI. If you can share your file, we should be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: I think it is reported issue to GPU (maybe OptiX) render ... try to render by CPU instead if issue persists ... few days ago I saw some report also here, I can't find it probably closed, since bugs are not allowed to report here.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for offering help and for the useful comments. Indeed, with CPU the lines disappear! I am quite surprised because, as I mentioned, I have often encountered this problem, that then has been going on for quite some time and quite a few versions. By the way I am using Blender on a MacMini.

Answer (score 0):

OK. As it was suggested, it turns out to be a bug with GPU render.